# java.sql.SQLException: Column 'grade' not found

Tags: java, sql, database, prepared-statement, resultset

i have 3 tables 
user(id,name),
course(id,name) and 
users_courses(user_id,course_id,grade)

and i used this query (which works on phpmyadmin) in DbCourse.java

```
    private final String GET_STUDENT_COURSES = "select * from users_courses where user_id = ? ";
```

and the method  i want to get hashmap with course name and the grade

```
public HashMap<String, Double> getHashMapStudentCourses(User user) {
    HashMap<String, Double> studentCourses = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(GET_STUDENT_COURSES);
        ps.setInt(1, user.getId());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            String courseName =(this.get_course(rs.getInt("course_id"))).getCourse_name();
            studentCourses.put(courseName,rs.getDouble("grade"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbCourse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return studentCourses;
}
```

this is the get_course method

```
 public Course get_course(int id) {
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(GET_COURSE);
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.first()) {
            return new Course(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbCourse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and i get this exception when i use it java.sql.SQLException: Column 'grade' not found.
please help i dont know where is the error

Guys after i commented the 2 line inside the while loop i get stackoverflow exception what is the reason

Comment: So does your table have a column called "grade" or is it called "grades"? Post the table structure.

Comment: no its called grade

Comment: after i commented the 2 line inside the while loop i get stackoverflow exception

Comment: Why don't you use join to get also course name?

Comment: Try `rs.getDouble(2)` instead of `rs.getDouble("grade")`.

Comment: i changed the query to select course_id,name,grade from courses,users_courses where courses.id = users_courses.course_id and user_id =?; and now i get stackoverflow exception

Comment: Leave the statement as it was and find out why the column `grade` is not found.  Use `rs.getDouble(2)` to get it. Also which rdbms is this?